# how to change the oracle schema dynamically via by spring boot JPA / Hibernate

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In my case whenever i executed the query the default schema was set in the session.

So with using `EntityManager` native query ill alter the session based on my request with updated schema . something like below

```
CreateNativeQuery(alter session set current_schema = some_name);
```

And after the successful update when i run my query , it was returning the default schema instead of the updated one ?

```
select sys_context('userenv' , 'current schema') from dual;
```

I understand that spring connection pool was creating this schema by default, but my question is there anyway to update the schema dynamically from code ? Kindly share your suggestions

Answer (score 2):

The `set current_schema` function only changes the default schema used when not fully qualifying object names in your queries, so

```
connect schema1/password;
alter session set current_schema = schema2;
select * from table_a;
```

would be the same as

```
connect schema1/password;
select * from schema2.table_a;
```

`set current_schema` doesn't change the schema/user to which you are actually connected, so your security profile will not change. It is also considered best practice to fully qualify your object references, especially if they are in a different schema than the one you log in to.

Also, if you are using a connection pool, altering your session will only affect the one thread you happen to be using when the command is issued. The next time you get a different connection thread from the pool, you will have a different physical database connection with the original session parameters.